# Using shareReplay() for non-idempotent HTTP requests

Tags: javascript, rxjs

If I wanted to use the `shareReplay()` operator for some of my HTTP requests, would I have to ensure that these calls were idempotent?

I wouldn't want to share the last emitted item(s) if they were expected to change right?